# Modx Evo Date Difference Snippet

Tags: code-snippets, modx

Using Modx evo, I am trying to use the following snippet to display the date difference between published date and current date (in days), but getting weird output. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$date2=$modx->documentObject['createdon'];
$date1=time();
$dateDiff = $date1 - $date2;
$daysOld = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
return $daysOld;
?>
```

Comment: First what you need to do - check format of createdon: `return print_r($modx->documentObject['createdon'],1);` and then ask again.

Comment: It give me following output: 1360951562 (Looks like the unix date stamp :(.

Comment: how about `$daysOld = round($dateDiff/(60*60*24));` ?

Comment: Okay used round as you suggested, yet the output is still incorrect. The createdon date is 2013/02/17 and it shows the output as 4 (should be 1 if current date is 18th).

Comment: Thanks Vasis, I should be using editedon parameter. And using round actually did work. It's working fine now. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the date is stored as a SQL-date, not a timestamp.

Read the docs: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Date+Formats

So, this should work:

```
$dateDiff = $time() - strtotime($modx->documentObject['createdon']);
$daysOld = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
return $daysOld;
```